# Android: Button to the south

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I've got a vertically orientated `LinearLayout` with two components: First a `ListView` and beneath a `Button`. I want the `ListView` to fill so much space that still the button fits beneath. In originally Java (Swing) using the `BorderLayout` that would be something like setting the `ListView` to the center and the `Button` to the south. How is that possible in out android context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the layout xml set android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight=1 for the listview.

Comment: I personally would have just used a `RelativeLayout`, but this will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve it.Consider Relative Layout is your root.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnBottom"/>

        <Button
            android:id="+id/btnBottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: using a fixed height for the button and copying this as marginBottom in the listview is not a good practice... I suggest to use layout_heigt="wrap_content" on the button and add an id (eg: buttonBottom). Then add a layoutAbove="@id/buttonBottom" and layout_alignParentTop="true" to the listView. Note: The <Button.. /> needs to be above the listview to achieve this.